# How to prevent mouse click event on Windows

Tags: windows, go, events

I record the mouse events on windows by using `robotgo` package. Package provides to get `bitmap` of clicked area but the latency of having bitmap is super sensitive situation here.

For example:
If I click any checkbox which is unchecked on the screen, provided bitmap must contains the state of unchecked but it provides me checked state and cannot simulate it with robotgo or cannot trigger click by using bitmap.

Solution to this scenario is that I need to prevent windows mouse click event until bitmap provided by the package (or adding some delay for click event) then trigger the click event on windows.

I made some research online but couldn't find a proper solution. How prevent click event on Windows in Go? Is it possible or is there any other way to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

A [low-level mouse hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644986(v=vs.85)) can eat mouse events. [`SendInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) can generate mouse input events.

You would have to set a flag somewhere so you don't eat your own fake input events.

Keep in mind that `SendInput` is not perfect (can be detected by other hooks) and playing with the input system like this is usually not the best solution. Adding 500ms (or some other delay) to every mouse click is going to be very annoying for your users.

It is better to use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) to get information about UI element states in other applications...